# why i send 201 status, but receive 302 status on the client

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, iis-7, status

In cgi server,i return like this

```
print ('Status: 201 Created')
print ('Content-Type: text/html')
print ('Location: http://10.1.146.174/index.html')
print ('')
print ('\n')
```

here is 201 status's explain:
The request has been fulfilled and resulted in a new resource being created. The newly created resource can be referenced by the URI(s) returned in the entity of the response, with the most specific URL for the resource given by a Location header field. The origin server MUST create the resource before returning the 201 status code. If the action cannot be carried out immediately, the server should respond with 202 (Accepted) response instead.

But actually,in client, the result is:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Redirect
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: http://10.1.146.174/index.html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 27 Nov 2011 05:36:18 GMT
Content-Length: 153
```

I have searched many times, but it doesn't work.
ps: the server is windows ii7
does anybody know this?

### thanks

it seems like iis7's problem.
does anybody now how to config iis7 about this problem.
i've remove all the isapi filters
but it still doesn't work....

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to configure IIS7 to return status 201 with a Location header through its CGI Module. I read one comment that suggested it is a feature of the CGI and FastCGI modules, not if IIS itself, so you may be able to change your integration.

I believe it is a bug: RFC2616 is very clear that a Location header with status 302 is a redirect but with status 201 it is not.

I have CGI scripts which return status 201 with Location headers. When I run them with IIS7/CGIModule the browser gets status 302 and redirects but when I run the same with Apache 2.2 the browser gets status 201 and does not redirect. So, depending on your other requirements, switching your web server to Apache might be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an IIS problem.  You're setting a **Location:** HTTP header, which tells the browser you want to do a redirect to another page.  Possibly IIS is intercepting this and filling out the HTTP response correctly with the status code of 302.  Just remove that line and I think this should work as you're expecting.

More info on the Location header:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location

If you're trying to setup a REST type response, add the URL of the resource created to the body of the document, not the headers.